# Change text color using Angular Material 15 custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change the default color of the texts using a custom theme in angular material 15.
This way doesn't work

```
(...)

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$ng-frontend-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $ng-frontend-primary,
    accent: $ng-frontend-accent,
    warn: $ng-frontend-warn,
  ),
  typography: typography.$my-app-typography,
  foreground: (
    base: black,
    divider: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    dividers: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12),
    disabled: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38),
    disabled-button: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26),
    disabled-text: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38),
    elevation: black, hint-text: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38),
    secondary-text: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54),
    icon: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54),
    icons: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54),
    text: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), // text color still rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    slider-min: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87),
    slider-off: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26),
    slider-off-active: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)
  )
));

(...)
```

Any one can help me?